PowerShell Constrained Language Mode doesn't work within scripts
I have an AppLocker policy that allows only scripts signed with a certificate from my company. This is the only script policy, no default created.
When I run a Windows PowerShell 5.1 or PowerShell 7 console (tried all this inside console and Terminal) on a Windows 11 machine, $ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode returns correctly ConstrainedLanguage (PowerShell 7 displays this information directly when launched)
I have got this very simple non signed script :
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode
[System.Console]::WriteLine("Hello")

When I type within the console the second line [System.Console]::WriteLine("Hello"), I got the expected error :
Cannot invoke method. Method invocation is supported only on core types in this language mode.
At line:1 char:1
+ [System.Console]::WriteLine("Hello")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodInvocationNotSupportedInConstrainedLanguage

But, when I run the script, here is the output :
FullLanguage
Hello

If I test the AppLocker rule with
Get-AppLockerPolicy -Effective | 
    Test-AppLockerPolicy -Path C:\Tests\test.ps1 -User Install #("Install" is my test user)

It returns correctly :
FilePath           PolicyDecision MatchingRule
--------           -------------- ------------
C:\Tests\test.ps1 DeniedByDefault

If I add a new AppLocker rule which denies to everyone for all paths, it returns correctly :
FilePath          PolicyDecision MatchingRule
--------          -------------- ------------
C:\Tests\test.ps1         Denied *

and when I run the script, I have got the same result, the script is running in FullLanguage Mode.
Any idea why this script is running in FullLanguage mode despite it is not signed, and why with UMCI policy (see EDIT 2), signed script is running in ContrainedLanguage Mode despite the signer is part of both policies (UMCI and AppLocker) ?
Thanks
EDIT
If I call the script within another one (or even itself), despite the first script still executes into FullLanguage Mode, I got the expected behavior for the script call :
C:\Tests\test.ps1: C:\Tests\test.ps1:3
Line |
   3 |  C:\Tests\test.ps1
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'C:\Tests\test.ps1' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable
     | program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
     | again.

EDIT 2
If I apply a Device Guard UMCI Policy while keeping my AppLocker policy, the script is correctly running in ConstrainedLanguage. This complains with the Microsoft statement (the blocked scripts throw error 8007 in event log but run in constrained mode). Script files are not members of the Device Guard UMCI Policy, only the signer is, and signed scripts are running in ContrainedLanguage too... but they should run in FullLanguage...

I'm in the same boat. I thought maybe this App ID Service ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/app-control-for-business/applocker/configure-the-application-identity-service ) was the issue, so I ran sc.exe config appidsvc start=auto and rebooted, and no change
